# Derivate new queries from existing ones

Tags: java, jpa

I'm doing basic pagination on entities.

```
public <T> PaginatedList<T> paginate(Class<T> entityClass, int currentPage, int pageSize) {
  long count = count(entityClass);
  TypedQuery<T> query = createQuery(entityClass);
  query.setFirstResult((currentPage - 1) * pageSize);
  query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
  return PaginatedList.of(query.getResultList(), count, currentPage, pageSize);
}

private <T> long count(Class<T> entityClass) {
  CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Long> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
  query.select(criteriaBuilder.count(query.from(entityClass)));
  return entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}

private <T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(Class<T> entityClass) {
  CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<T> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
  Root<T> entity = query.from(entityClass);
  query.select(entity);
  return entityManager.createQuery(query);
}
```

As you see, I'm building the queries from scratch.

Is there any way to perform the same mechanism using a reference query? What I mean is that I'd love to write something like this:

```
public <T> PaginatedList<T> paginate(TypedQuery<T> query, int currentPage, int pageSize) {
  TypedQuery<T> q = safeCopy(query);
  long count = count(q);
  q.setFirstResult((currentPage - 1) * pageSize);
  q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
  return PaginatedList.of(q.getResultList(), count, currentPage, pageSize);
}
```

This way, I could write my basic query as it pleases me (even as a named query) and then simply paginate it using this method.

If this is possible, how should I write both my `safeCopy` and `count` method?

Oh I forgot: I use Java 8 and JavaEE 7 on WildFly 8 if that's any indication.

Also, please note that this is a simplified example. I actually use several callbacks to write my `select`, `where` and `orderBy` clauses.

Comment: on Hibernate there are `DetachedCriteria`s for that I think. I dont know if JPA has the same thing

Comment: Thank you for the information though I'm speaking about JPA and only JPA. I will not switch to Hibernate only for this feature.